# Objective C ARC NSMutableArray - returned from function - not released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I have been reading lots of posts and am confused as to why this is a problem - shouldn't the ARC handle this ?

Utilizing replies below I was able to isolate the problem to "Moves" as the culprit - it appears to never be released and keeps consuming memory even though it is set to nil. Moves is set in two places at the bottom of Grid.m - methods FindRandomMove and that is called in the recursiveProcess routine.

The general structure is a grid made up of Columns, made up of Cells. The Cells value are randomly generated to make a puzzle. This is done many times to test puzzle solutions.

The program starts by running generateTest in Grid.m

(I appreciate all comments on any part of the code if I am doing something that does not follow best practices or there is a better/proper way of doing it).

Full test code to follow:

```
Cell.h
@interface Cell : NSObject {

CFMutableBitVectorRef _validNumbersBitVector;
NSUInteger _answerNumber; 
UIColor * _color;
NSUInteger _cellRow;
NSUInteger _cellCol;
}   

@property CFMutableBitVectorRef validNumbersBitVector;
@property NSUInteger answerNumber; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor * color;
@property NSUInteger cellRow;
@property NSUInteger cellCol;
```

// set methods

```
- (void) setValid:         (BOOL)valid   number:(NSUInteger)numberToChange;
- (void) setAllNumbersToValidState:(BOOL) valid;

// get methods

- (BOOL) numberIsValid: (NSUInteger)numberToCheck;
- (NSUInteger) getRandomValidNumber;
- (NSUInteger) validNumberCount;

@end

Cell.m

#import "Cell.h"

#define RANGE CFRangeMake(0,9)

@implementation Cell

@synthesize validNumbersBitVector = _validNumbersBitVector;
@synthesize answerNumber = _answerNumber; 
@synthesize color = _color;
@synthesize cellRow = _cellRow;
@synthesize cellCol = _cellCol;

-(id) init {

    if ((self = [super init])){

        _answerNumber = 0;
        _validNumbersBitVector =CFBitVectorCreateMutable(NULL,10);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setValid:(BOOL)valid number:(NSUInteger)numberToChange {

    CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(self.validNumbersBitVector, numberToChange - 1, !valid);
}

-(void) setAllNumbersToValidState:(BOOL) valid{

    CFBitVectorSetBits(self.validNumbersBitVector, RANGE, !valid);
}

-(NSUInteger) validNumberCount{

    return CFBitVectorGetCountOfBit(self.validNumbersBitVector, RANGE, 0);
}

- (BOOL) numberIsValid: (NSUInteger)numberToCheck{

     return !CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(self.validNumbersBitVector, numberToCheck - 1);
}

- (NSUInteger) getRandomValidNumber{

    NSUInteger pos;
    NSUInteger counter = 0;
    NSUInteger number = 0;
    NSUInteger validCount = 0;

    validCount = CFBitVectorGetCountOfBit(self.validNumbersBitVector, RANGE, 0);

    if (validCount > 0) {
        pos = (rand() %(validCount)) + 1;

        while (counter < pos){
            number ++;
            if (!CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(self.validNumbersBitVector, number - 1) ) {
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}    
@end
```

Moves.h

```
#import "Cell.h"

@interface Moves : NSObject {       
    NSUInteger _row;
    NSUInteger _col;
    NSUInteger _newValue;
    Cell     * _cell;
}   
@property NSUInteger row;
@property NSUInteger col;
@property NSUInteger newValue;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Cell     * cell;

@end
```

Moves.m

```
#import "Moves.h"

@implementation Moves

@synthesize row = _row;
@synthesize col = _col;
@synthesize newValue = _newValue;
@synthesize cell =  _cell;

-(id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _row = 0;
        _col = 0;
        _newValue = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Grid.h

```
#import "Col.h"
#import "Moves.h"

@interface Grid : NSObject {

NSMutableArray* _rowData;
    NSMutableArray* _emptyCells;
    BOOL _puzzleSolved;
BOOL _bruteForceEnd;    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * rowData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * emptyCells;
@property BOOL puzzleSolved;
@property BOOL bruteForceEnd;

- (void) generateTest;
- (void) initializePuzzle;
- (Cell *) cellAtRow:(NSUInteger) pRow andCol:(NSUInteger) pCol;
- (void) setAnswerNumber:(NSUInteger)newAnswerNumber cell:(Cell *) pCell;
- (Moves*) FindRandomMove;
- (NSUInteger) recursiveProcess:(NSUInteger)BFCount;

@end
```

Grid.m

```
#import "Grid.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation Grid 

@synthesize rowData = _rowData;
@synthesize emptyCells = _emptyCells;
@synthesize puzzleSolved = _puzzleSolved;
@synthesize bruteForceEnd = _bruteForceEnd;

- (id) init 
{
if ((self = [super init])) {

    _rowData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    _emptyCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSUInteger i;

    for (i = 0; i<9; i++) {
        Col *tmpCol = [[Col alloc] initWithRow:i + 1];
        [_rowData addObject:tmpCol];
     }
}
return self;
}

- (void) generateTest {

for (int mloop2 = 1; mloop2 < 10000;mloop2 ++) {       
    for (int mloop = 0; mloop < 1000; mloop ++) {
        [self initializePuzzle];        
        [self recursiveProcess:0];
    }
}
}

- (void) initializePuzzle{

self.bruteForceEnd = NO;
[self.emptyCells removeAllObjects];

for (Col * tmpCol in self.rowData){
    for (Cell * answerCell in tmpCol.colData){
        answerCell.answerNumber = 0;
        [self.emptyCells addObject:answerCell];
    }
}
}

- (Cell *) cellAtRow:(NSUInteger) pRow andCol:(NSUInteger) pCol {

Cell * tmpCell;
tmpCell = [[self.rowData objectAtIndex:pRow - 1] cellAtCol:pCol];
return tmpCell;
tmpCell = nil;
}


- (void) setAnswerNumber:(NSUInteger)newAnswerNumber cell:(Cell *) pCell{

if (pCell.answerNumber != newAnswerNumber) {
    if (newAnswerNumber == 0 ) [self.emptyCells addObject: pCell];
    if (pCell.answerNumber == 0) [self.emptyCells removeObject:pCell]; 
    pCell.answerNumber = newAnswerNumber; 
}    
pCell = nil;
}

- (NSUInteger) recursiveProcess:(NSUInteger)BFCount{

Moves * nextMove; 
Cell * answerCell;
NSUInteger counter;
NSUInteger number;
NSUInteger row;
NSUInteger col;

BFCount ++;
nextMove = [self FindRandomMove];
number = nextMove.newValue;
row = nextMove.row;
col = nextMove.col;
nextMove = nil;

answerCell = [self cellAtRow:row andCol:col];
[self setAnswerNumber:number cell:answerCell];
answerCell = nil;

if (BFCount > 48) self.bruteForceEnd=YES; 
if (self.puzzleSolved) self.bruteForceEnd = YES;
if (self.bruteForceEnd) return BFCount;
counter = [self recursiveProcess:BFCount]; // try again
if (counter > 50) NSLog(@"brute force 50");
return BFCount;
}

- (Moves *) FindRandomMove{

Moves * tMove =[[Moves alloc] init]; 
NSUInteger col = 0;
NSUInteger row = 0;
NSUInteger possibleCount = 0;
NSMutableArray * possibleCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:82];
NSUInteger selectedPossible;
NSUInteger numberToUse = 0;
Cell * answerCell ;

NSUInteger validCount = 0;

for ( Cell * tmpCell in self.emptyCells){

    validCount=tmpCell.validNumberCount;       
    [possibleCells addObject:tmpCell];
    possibleCount ++;                   

}

if (possibleCount != 0){
    selectedPossible = 0;       

    if (possibleCount > 1) selectedPossible = rand() % (possibleCount - 1);

    answerCell = [possibleCells objectAtIndex:selectedPossible];

    row = answerCell.cellRow;
    col = answerCell.cellCol;
    numberToUse = answerCell.getRandomValidNumber;
    answerCell = nil;

}

possibleCells = nil;
tMove.row = row;
tMove.col = col;
tMove.newValue = numberToUse;

return tMove;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER BASED ON UPDATE CODE IN POST:**

This whole implementation is fairly convoluted. I'm going to limit my answer specifically to memory mgmt issues. In `generateTest` you end up calling `initializePuzzle` 10,000,000 times and within each iteration `recursiveProcess` could be called up to 49 times. So, you are allocating a `Moves` object up to 490,000,000 times. Your problem is not that the object isn't getting released, it's that your run loop is allocating a huge number of objects which don't get released until the run loop is over. A quick fix for your test code would be to do the following:

```
- (NSUInteger)recursiveProcess:(NSUInteger)BFCount
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Frankly, I would rewrite this to simplify the logic and eliminate the recursion. Also, if you must do something that iterates this many times, you should do this processing in the background and allow your UI thread to remain unblocked. That allows users to do things (e.g. cancel the game, restart, etc) w/o waiting.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

From the code you posted I can't tell the context of cellObjects and what is happening to it after you call `[cell objectsRemoveAllObjects]`. If you are done with the array instead of removing the objects just do `cellObjects = nil`.

As @Jesse said, you should ensure you haven't created a retain cycle. If any of your processing is happening in the background or dispatched with blocks that could cause a retain cycle depending on how you are assigning/referencing objects. For example, referring to self inside a dispatched block.

At compile time, ARC will make sure that orphaned objects(e.g. no other object has a strong reference to them) are released properly.

If you don't discover the issue, you could post more code showing the complete lifecycle of the array that isn't being released. The specifics of your processing are not important other than any code that creates, assigns, or nils the array or objects referencing the array.

Comment: A question about your comment to referring to self. Cell.h I define the interface properties _xxxx. then use property with out the _.  Ex NSUinteger _cellRow;  property NSUInteger cellRow; In the Cell.m - synthesize cellRow = _cellRow;  I then use self.cellRow within functions in Cell.m. (The only time I use _cellRow is in the init); is this correct ?

Comment: You can use iVars wherever you want. If you have a property defined you can use `self.propertyName`. Using the getter/setter (e.g. self.propertyName) means the setter/getter function is called. The synthesized versions are generated based on your property definition. When you use the iVar you are directly assigning whatever value you want and if not under ARC, you need to make sure to release the old value (if necessary) and retain the new one (if necessary). What is needed depends on the data type and how you want the iVar/property to work.

Comment: Well I was hoping not to have to do this. but I am stuck. I created a brand new project with most of the code stripped out to try and isolate the problem. I did Isolate the problem (thanks to your tips), but I am still not sure why it is occurring - the profiler/allocations shows that "Moves" is a culprit. Keeps growing. Moves is created in two places - findRandomMove and a recursive routine -recursiveProcess. I have set it to Nil after use - as suggested, but I must be missing something. Sorry for all the code coming..basically - the structure is a Grid - contains Columns which contains cells

Comment: Many Thanks - Yes this code is convoluted - The large loop is just for simulation purposes - normally would only be called a few times - but this exaggerates the problem and made it easier to identify my memory management mistakes...

Comment: Tested your solution with autorelease pool - problem fixed ! I appreciated your time in reviewing this problem!

Comment: No problem. My last comment in my original answer was wrong. The specifics of your processing is really the cause here. The huge loop + the recursion is all happening within a single run loop. You would have had the same issue w/o ARC if using autoreleased objects. Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've got a retain loop. In this case, perhaps one of the cells is holding a reference to your "cellObjects" subset? If a cell holds on to the subset array, which holds on to the cell, then nothing will ever be freed.

If that's the case (or if a cell is holding on to something which holds on to something which ... holds on to the cell subset) then you'll have to break that chain somehow; perhaps by nilling out something you're done with, or making something a __weak pointer.

Retain loops don't show up as leaks, but if you use the heap instrument, it will show you what might be keeping your array around.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the heap instrument.I will do more analysis and post back. I suspect it is a retain loop.